# How to set variable index outside of function and execute after a function has finished

Tags: jquery

2 Questions, firstly I have this code:

```
    function Question(container, question_list, chosenAnswer) {
    this.container = container.empty();
    this.question_list = question_list;

    if(question_list.length == 1) {

        container.append('<div class="answer">' + question_list[0] + '</div>'); 

    } else if (question_list.length == 2) {

        for(var i=0;i<question_list.length;i++){
            container.append('<div class="two_q'+(i+1)+'">' + question_list[i] + '</div>');
        }
        addClickOn(container, chosenAnswer);


    } else {

        for(var i=0;i<question_list.length;i++){
            container.append('<div class="four_q'+(i+1)+'">' + question_list[i] + '</div>');
        }
        addClickOn(container, chosenAnswer);
    }
}

function addClickOn(container, chosenAnswer)
{
    this.container = container;
    $(container.children()).on('click', function() {
        selected = $(this);
        chosenAnswer= $(this).index();
        selected.siblings().fadeOut();
        selected.animate({
            width: container.width(),
            height: container.height()
        });
        selected.fadeOut();
    });
}


    var question_list1 = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4"];
    var question_list2 = ["Statement1", "Statement2"];
    var answer = ["Answer"];
    var chosenAnswer;

new Question($('div.question_container'), question_list2);
console.log(chosenAnswer);
```

1. Why is chosenAnswer undefined on the console log? I haven't defined it, but I have passed it through the functions till it gets set on the click event.
2. When one of the boxes is clicked and the animation has finished, I then want to return this chosenAnswer and repeat the Question function with a new array. How do I do this?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a **call by value** language.  You can't modify the value of a variable in the calling context like you can with a C++ `&foo` reference parameter.

If you made "chosenAnswer" an object, then the function could use the reference to that object passed in as  a parameter to modify the object contents.  It's hard to say exactly how to fix your code because it's so unidiomatic.

Your use of `this` in "addClickOn()" is incorrect also. Again, it's hard to say what the code should do instead, but `this` in that function won't refer to anything useful because of the way the function is called.

Comment: This within the click function works fine, if any criticism I should have used chosenAnswer = selected.index() to avoid repeating. It refers to which css boxes to animate, and would ideally return which box was clicked. Thanks for the contribution Pointy.

Comment: Inside "addClickOn", `this` will be set to `window`, which is why it "works".  That's because when "addClickOn()" is called, nothing is done that would make `this` be bound to any other value.